Microsoft ASP.net Identity Owin Email login not working for specific username
We are having a weird issue when utilizing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin for logins. We have this hosted on an IIS server, with at least 50 people successfully logging in and utilizing the software. There is one user that has Enoch@theirdomainname.com. This caused an issue when logging in and authorizing the user. We created a false email address utilizing Enoch@Ourdomainname.com to bypass this issue, but it gave them access for about two weeks, and then it provided the same exact issue that their domain name caused.
I have tried searching for a reason why Enoch would cause an issue with Microsoft Owin, but I came across with nothing. Has anyone else had a similar issue, or anything close to this happening?
